# how to show contents of uploaded csv in shiny

Tags: shiny

My `ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(stats)
library(caret)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Predicting Resources for Vessel"),
   title = "Resource Prediction",

   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose a Import BAPLE(.CSV) file to upload:",
                  accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),

        fileInput("file2", "Choose a Export BAPLE(.csv) file to upload:",
                  accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),

        fileInput("file3", "Choose a Import/Export containers yard location(.CSV) file to upload:",
                  accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),

        tags$hr(),
        h4("Manual Input:"),
        numericInput("Restow_40","Total Restows for 40ft Container:", 0, min = 0, max = 999999, step = 1),
        textInput("Berth","Vessel Berth Location (CB3/CB4)"),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")

        ),
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Raw Data", dataTableOutput("data")),
          tabPanel("Output", verbatimTextOutput("pred_output"))

        )
  )
    )
))
```

This is my `server.r` file

```
library(shiny)
library(stats)
#library(caret)
library(mlr)
library(data.table)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 ######################### Reading the required files ###################################

  import_baple <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
})

  export_baple <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file2
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })

  import_export_yard <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file3
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    import_baple()
  })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    export_baple()
  })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    import_export_yard()
  })
})
```

I want all the three files when uploaded to be displayed in `Raw Data` tab. When I upload first two files no content is displayed in the `Raw Tab`, but when I upload the third file content is displayed in the tab. I am not getting where I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Each input/output element needs a unique identifier, otherwise Shiny doesn't know which of the elements with the given identifier to use. So where you have:

```
tabPanel("Raw Data", dataTableOutput("data"))
```

In your UI and:

```
output$data <- renderDataTable({
  import_baple()
})

output$data <- renderDataTable({
  export_baple()
})

output$data <- renderDataTable({
  import_export_yard()
})
```

In your server, what you actually need is more like:

```
# UI
tabPanel("Raw Data", 
    dataTableOutput("import_baple_data"),
    dataTableOutput("explort_baple_data"),
    dataTableOutput("import_export_data")
)

# Server
output$import_baple_data <- renderDataTable({
  import_baple()
})

output$export_baple_data <- renderDataTable({
  export_baple()
})

output$import_export_data <- renderDataTable({
  import_export_yard()
})
```